# How to generate a million tuples dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Below is the code for generating a million tuples DataFrame. Any ideas on making it faster?

```
   for  x in np.arange(1000000):
        df_tmp= pd.DataFrame({"SalesDate":[random.choice(SalesDates)],
                   "SalesDistrict":[random.choice(district)],
                   "ProductSold":[random.choice(product)],
                   "SalesAmount":[random.SystemRandom().uniform(1,5000)]})
        df=pd.concat([df,df_tmp])
    
    df.set_index("SalesDate",inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One idea is create list of DataFrames first and then run only one `pd.concat`:

```
dfs = []
for  x in np.arange(1000000):
     df_tmp= pd.DataFrame({"SalesDate":[random.choice(SalesDates)],
                           "SalesDistrict":[random.choice(district)],
                           "ProductSold":[random.choice(product)],
                           "SalesAmount":[random.SystemRandom().uniform(1,5000)]})
     dfs.append(df_tmp)
    
df = pd.concat(dfs).set_index("SalesDate")
```

Another idea, faster is generate DataFrame by [`numpy.random.choice`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.choice.html) and [`numpy.random.uniform`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/random/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html):

```
N = 1000000
df = pd.DataFrame({"SalesDistrict":np.random.choice(district, size=N),
                   "ProductSold":np.random.choice(product, size=N),
                   "SalesAmount":np.random.uniform(1,5000, N)},
                    index=np.random.choice(SalesDates, size=N))
```

Comment: a rough estimate for the code to complete is 40 mins.

Comment: @DennisKwone - ya, try second one.